# VHDL: Type Mismatch Error (Ripple Carry Adder)

Tags: variables, vhdl, type-mismatch

I'm relatively new to VHDL, so I apologize before hand for the solution to this question probably appearing painstakingly obvious to most of you. In this code, I am trying to simulate a 4-bit ripple carry adder. However, when I check the syntax of the code a I run into a few errors having to do with type mismatches.

Relevant Code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity toplevel is
    Port ( x : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           y : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           sum : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
           count : out  STD_LOGIC);
end toplevel;

40: architecture Structure of toplevel is

signal c1, c2, c3 : STD_LOGIC;
component mytutorial02 
    Port(
    x : in STD_LOGIC;
    y : in STD_LOGIC;
    cin : in STD_LOGIC;
    sum : out STD_LOGIC;
    count : out STD_LOGIC);
end component;

begin

54: Stage0: mytutorial02 port map(x=>x(0), y=>(0), cin=>cin, sum=>sum(0), count=>c1);
55: Stage1: mytutorial02 port map(x=>x(1), y=>(1), cin=>c1, sum=>sum(1), count=>c2);
56: Stage2: mytutorial02 port map(x=>x(2), y=>(2), cin=>c2, sum=>sum(2), count=>c3);
57: Stage3: mytutorial02 port map(x=>x(3), y=>(3), cin=>c3, sum=>sum(3), count=>count);

end Structure;
```

&

```
entity mytutorial02 is
Port ( x : in  STD_LOGIC;
       y : in  STD_LOGIC;
       cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
       sum : out  STD_LOGIC;
       count : out  STD_LOGIC);

end mytutorial02;

architecture Behavioral of mytutorial02 is

begin

sum  <= (x xor y xor cin);
count <= (cin and x) or (x and y) or (cin and y);

end Behavioral;
```

The errors specifically are:

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:839 - "M:/ece230/tutorial02/toplevel.vhd" Line 54:
>   Type std_logic does not match with the integer literal
>
> ERROR:HDLCompiler:839 - "M:/ece230/tutorial02/toplevel.vhd" Line 55:
>   Type std_logic does not match with the integer literal
>
> ERROR:HDLCompiler:839 - "M:/ece230/tutorial02/toplevel.vhd" Line 56:
>   Type std_logic does not match with the integer literal
>
> ERROR:HDLCompiler:839 - "M:/ece230/tutorial02/toplevel.vhd" Line 57:
>   Type std_logic does not match with the integer literal
>
> ERROR:HDLCompiler:854 - "M:/ece230/tutorial02/toplevel.vhd" Line 40:
>   Unit  ignored due to previous errors. VHDL file

Can anyone give a quick suggestion/insight as how to fix this? I tried to troubleshoot it myself, but couldn't identify what was wrong. It appears to me that all the variables are listed as STD_LOGIC...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll kick yourself ...`y=>(0),`

Comment: Haha, damn it. I definitely am kicking myself. Thank you. If you want to directly post that as an answer I'll award you the correct answer... if that interests you to begin with.

Comment: You also can't use `40` as a label which must be an identifier (either a basic identifier starting with a letter, or an extended identifier starting with a backslash). Also architecture bodies aren't decorated with labels - they are named, and you can't have two labels, e.g. `54: Stage0:` Fixing Brian's actuals (4 places), Labels (5 places with the architecture) and adding a context clause (`library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;`  to the mytutorial02 entity/architecture and your code analyzes.

Comment: ^Thanks for this. I actually just threw those in to make it easier to identify which lines the error codes were referencing. In hindsight I should have mentioned that in my original post.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve") -*Some people might be prepared to load the parts up, and actually try them to test the answer they're about to post.*  Your line numbers as labels just add five more errors.